# Create bounding box polygon from extent of point features in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, extents, polygon-creation

I have a linestring table (`table a`) and a point table (`table b`). What I want is to extract the start points from the features in the linestring table and union them with the point features in the point table.
Thereafter I want to group the points from the values in the column 'dokument' and create surrounding bounding boxes/envelopes (polygons) from the union subquery.

I have tried the following in pgAdmin:

```
    SELECT
    row_number() OVER () AS id,
    p.dokument,
    ST_Envelope(ST_Collect(p.the_geom))::geometry(Polygon,7416) AS the_geom
FROM(SELECT
        a.dokument,
        ST_StartPoint(a.geom) AS the_geom
    FROM
        schema.table_a a
    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        b.dokument,
        b.geom as the_geom
    FROM
        schema.table_b b
) AS p
GROUP BY p.dokument;
```

Unfortunately I get this error message saying: `"ERROR:  Geometry type (Point) does not match column type (Polygon) SQL state: 22023"`

Comment: Have you tried your union all as a standalone query first to check if it's OK, or if it comes when generating the envelope?

Comment: The [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html) says that a single point envelope is a point, not a polygon. You can try to add a small buffer to the envelope first.

Comment: If your `UNION` returns only a single `POINT` per `dokument` grouping - either because there's only one, or those present are equal - the `ST_Envelope` will be a `POINT`. The *typemod* qualified `CAST` to `GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 7416)` thus fails, as the geometry types don't match.

Comment: @kasper It comes when generating the envelope. In fact I succeeded doing the envelope operation on the linestring table standalone, resulting in a polygon table. The problem occurs introducing the point layers into the operation, perhaps due to the reason geozelot stresses in his answer